# running series of commands gives other result than running them on script

Tags: scripts, directory, chmod, mkdir

this is the script:

```
#!/bin/sh
rm -rf git/
mkdir -p git/{c,ds/{include,test},projects,quizzes,system_programming}
find git/ -type d -exec touch {}/dummy.md \;
```

This is the wanted result:

```
git/
├── c
│   └── dummy.md
├── ds
│   ├── dummy.md
│   ├── include
│   │   └── dummy.md
│   └── test
│       └── dummy.md
├── dummy.md
├── projects
│   └── dummy.md
├── quizzes
│   └── dummy.md
└── system_programming
    └── dummy.md

7 directories, 8 files
```

That happens when I run each of the commands separately one by one.

When I run the script, by changing its permissions: `chmod +x script_name.sh`

I get:

```
git/
├── {c,ds
│   ├── dummy.md
│   └── {include,test},projects,quizzes,system_programming}
│       └── dummy.md
└── dummy.md

2 directories, 3 files
```

I see the problem is in `mkdir` command by creating the wrong hierarchy of directories.

So,I checked the `chmod` [command](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod),
I run `chmod +x+w script_name.sh` but I get the same result.

Why is that?
Thanks.

Comment: Your problem is with the she-bang, "sh". bash is what expands the { and }. You probably use bash on command line and /bin/sh is pointed to probably dash. Use `#!/bin/bash`,

Comment: Thanks, that solved the problem. So, if I want to use a command that has `{ }` in script, so I must use `#!/bin/bash` instead of `#!/bin/sh`?

Comment: @muru Thanks, that clarifies.